# What are the specifications for a mini-jack shutter cord?

Tags: shutter-release, triggers

The Canon EOS digital bodies I've had use a mini phono jack for a remote shutter button. I see several brands on B&H etc that all look identical ([like this one](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/765659-REG/Vello_RS_C1II_RS_C1II_Wired_Remote_Switch.htmlhttp://)) with the exact same locking button. I see some are advertised to work on various brands, not just one, so I ask, are they all standard and interchangable?

You'll notice that the prices vary considerably too. Mine is the cheapest possible, so much so that I wonder how they can even cover shipping.  It seems to no longer work, so I'm wondering *how* they work. Is it simple continuity between different pairs if the tip-ring-sleeve connections, or is there some circuitry involved?

I'd like to **know the specification**, so I can possibly fix mine, or just use my own button on that cord.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I happened across a [link](http://www.diyphotography.net/release_cable_for_canon_dslr/) in a comment by @ysap in an [obliquely related question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9294/are-there-downsides-to-a-wireless-infrared-remote-shutter-release?rq=1) I surfed into.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 4):

It is not just Canon bodies. Almost every brand of camera that uses a mini-stereo jack has the exact same pinout: The tip is the full press wire, the middle is the half press wire, and the base is the common ground. Even cameras which need other shape connectors almost all use the same three connections, they just vary the shape and arrangement of them.

There is at least one exception: Panasonic uses a single wire plus ground to signal both a half and full press by placing resistors of different values in the circuit depending on the switch position. Everything you ever wanted to know about remote cable release connections: http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/